# XML file offset and XPath insert element

Tags: python, xml, file, xpath, offset

I wonder if there is any way to obtain an XPath based (only) on the offset in the file representation
In my file

`<xml>......<tag>element</tag>`

for example, the offsets 16 to 23 could give the xpath '/xml/tag'
i'm using etree module with Python
thanks in advance for lightning on this

Answer (score 1):

**No, not with XPath**.

XPath treats an XML document after it is parsed as a tree of nodes (the  W3C **[XML Infoset model](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-infoset/)**) and any lexical representation is lost at that time.